# Ordinary Differential Equation Question 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering whether someone might be able to point me in the right direction for this ODE that I am trying to solve?

It is:

$\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{x}{s}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{u}{x}$ with $s$ some constant.

I have tried separating the variables but that did not work...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use Laplace transforms? And do you have initial conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange to get

$$x u' + u = (x u)' = \frac{x^2}{s} - \frac{x}{2} \implies x u = \frac{x^3}{3 s} - \frac{x^2}{4} + C$$